# ASP.NET MVC3 form collection is 0 during jQuery ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I am attempting to POST to a method that returns a bunch of data using the [jQuery.ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/); however whenever the request is handled by the server my form collection's keys count is 0 and so my view model isn't populated which is a problem.

I am applying applying the ajax to my form's submit like this:

```
 $(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.action,
        data: form.serialize(),
        contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            var d = new Date();
            var str = d.toString() + result;
            $('#dynamicContent').html(str);
        }
    });

});
```

My form is created like this:

```
  @Using Html.BeginForm("GetContent", "TheController", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "GetContentForm"})
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.SelectedTypeID, New SelectList(Html.NullListItemOptionList(Model.TypeOptions.ToList, "Please Choose"), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedTypeID), New With {.onchange = " $(this).parents('form').submit();"})
            @<input type="submit" value="Refresh" style="cursor: pointer" />
  End Using
  <div id="dynamicContent">
  </div>
```

My controller method is:

```
 <HttpPost()>
    Function GetContent(ByVal collection As FormCollection) As PartialViewResult

        Dim itemsVM As New ItemsViewModel
        TryUpdateModel(itemsVM, collection)
        Return PartialView("PartialItems", itemsVM)
    End Function
```

It's almost as if the serialization of the form is not working but I don't know how to fix this. I would really appreciate some insight into why this isn't working.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the contentType, you aren't sending html to the server.

Comment: I want to send content to the server. I want to send the SelectedTypeID.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the contentType and it worked...now I have another issue because I'm still not getting anything back from the server....but at least my form collections has stuff in it.

Comment: I'd recommend moving that to a 2nd question, focused more on the ASP side of things

Comment: Nah I figured it out. Was something I did in attempts to debug the problem with setting the content type. Could you please post your answer as an answer so that I can mark it as such :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending form params, the `contentType` you are using is incorrect, which in turn causes the server to not receive your data because it's expecting html and is not receiving any. To solve it, simply remove the `contentType` option from `$.ajax`.